# Tensorflow: Can't understand ctc_beam_search_decoder() output sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, beam-search

I am using Tensorflow's `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder()` to decode the output of a RNN doing some many-to-many mapping (i.e., multiple softmax outputs for each network cell).

A simplified version of the network's output and the Beam search decoder is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 4
sequence_max_len = 5
num_classes = 3

y_pred = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, sequence_max_len, num_classes))
y_pred_transposed = tf.transpose(y_pred,
                                 perm=[1, 0, 2])  # TF expects dimensions [max_time, batch_size, num_classes]
logits = tf.log(y_pred_transposed)
sequence_lengths = tf.to_int32(tf.fill([batch_size], sequence_max_len))
decoded, log_probabilities = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(logits,
                                                           sequence_length=sequence_lengths,
                                                           beam_width=3,
                                                           merge_repeated=False, top_paths=1)

decoded = decoded[0]
decoded_paths = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(decoded)  # Shape: [batch_size, max_sequence_len]

with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    softmax_outputs = np.array([[[0.1, 0.1, 0.8], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]],
                                [[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]],
                                [[0.1, 0.7, 0.2], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]],
                                [[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]]])

    decoded_paths = session.run(decoded_paths, feed_dict = {y_pred: softmax_outputs})
    print(decoded_paths)
```

The output in this case is:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

My understanding is that the output tensor should be of dimensions `[batch_size, max_sequence_len]`, with each row containing the indices of the relevant classes in the found path.

In this case I would expect the output to be similar to:

```
[[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

What am I not understanding about how `ctc_beam_search_decoder` works?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As indicated in [tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_beam_search_decoder), the shape of the output is not `[batch_size, max_sequence_len]`. Instead, it is

```
[batch_size, max_decoded_length[j]]
```

(with `j=0` in your case).

Based on the beginning of section 2 of [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf) (which is cited in the [github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/ctc_ops.py)), `max_decoded_length[0]` is bounded from above by `max_sequence_len`, but they are not necessarily equal. The relevant citation is:

> Let S be a set of training examples drawn from a fixed distribution
>   D_{XxZ}. The input space X = (R^m) is the set of all sequences of m
>   dimensional real valued vectors. The target space Z = L* is the set of
>   all sequences over the (finite) alphabet L of labels. In general, we
>   refer to elements of L* as label sequences or labellings. Each example
>   in S consists of a pair of sequences (x, z). The target sequence z =
>   (z1, z2, ..., zU) **is at most as long** as the input sequence x = (x1,
>   x2, ..., xT ), i.e. U<=T. Since the input and target sequences are
>   not generally the same length, there is no a priori way of aligning
>   them.

In fact, `max_decoded_length[0]` depends on the specific matrix `softmax_outputs`. In particular, two such matrices with exactly the same dimensions can result in different `max_decoded_length[0]`.

For example, if you replace the row

```
softmax_outputs = np.array([[[0.1, 0.1, 0.8], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1], [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]],
                                [[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]],
                                [[0.1, 0.7, 0.2], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]],
                                [[0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7], [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]]])
```

with the rows

```
np.random.seed(7)
r=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(4,5,3))
softmax_outputs=r/np.sum(r,2).reshape(4,5,1)
```

you'll get the output

```
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

(in the above examples, `softmax_outputs` consists of logits and it is exactly of the same dimensions as the matrix you provided).

On the other hand, changing the seed to `np.random.seed(50)` gives the output

```
[[1 0]
 [1 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

**P.S.**

Regarding the last part of your question:

> In this case I would expect the output to be similar to:
>
> ```
> [[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
>  [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
>  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
> ```

Note that, based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/connectionist_temporal_classification__ctc_#ctc_beam_search_decoder),  `num_classes` actually represents `num_labels + 1`. Specifically:

> The inputs Tensor's innermost dimension size, `num_classes`, represents
>   `num_labels + 1` classes, where `num_labels` is the number of true labels,
>   and the largest value (`num_classes - 1`) is reserved for the blank
>   label.
>
> For example, for a vocabulary containing 3 labels [a, b, c],
>   `num_classes = 4` and the labels indexing is {a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, blank:
>   3}.

So the true labels in your case are 0 and 1, and 2 is reserved for the blank label.   The blank label represents the situation of observing no label (section 3.1 [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf)):

> A CTC network has a softmax output layer (Bridle, 1990) with one more
>   unit than there are labels in L. The activations of the first |L|
>   units are interpreted as the probabilities of observing the
>   corresponding labels at particular times. **The activation of the extra
>   unit is the probability of observing a ‘blank’, or no label.** Together,
>   these outputs define the probabilities of all possible ways of
>   aligning all possible label sequences with the input sequence.